# \def taking next word as argument?

Tags: macros, tex-core, parsing

This question is a variant of my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10426/def-taking-rest-of-the-line-as-argument) requesting a macro that takes the rest of the line as argument. I would like to write a macro that would take the next word as argument, where word boundary is defined as a space or punctuation (say anything which is not a letter, a digit, or the colon character).

The difficulty lies with the fact that a normal `\def` can be set to expect a specific character, not a set of characters.

This is not a theoretical challenge---the concrete application is a macro that will do better references, so instead of writing `Lemma~\cite{Lemma:Kantor}`, one could write `\cf Lemma Kantor`

An approximation is

```
\def\cf #1 #2 {#1~\ref{#1:#2}}
```

but of course it would fail in cases it is used just before punctuation.

Comment: A similar problem, but not quite the same, was discussed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/parse-and-execute-the-next-word-as-a-command).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to read every character on its own using a loop. Actually you need to look ahead using `\futurelet` because a space would otherwise be removed by the argument grapper.

The following code works and treats line breaks as spaces. One colon is allowed as separator between the two words instead of a space. If you want to allow multiple colons you have to add them into the `if` list in `\cf@@`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\cf{%
  \begingroup
  \def\name{}%
  \cf@
}

\def\cf@{%
  \futurelet\ntoken\cf@@
}

\def\cf@@{%
  \ifcase 0%
    \ifx\ntoken\@sptoken 0\else
    \ifcat a\ntoken 1\else
    \ifcat 0\ntoken 2\fi% test of token is catcode "other"
    \fi\fi
  \relax
    \expandafter\cf@end
  \or
    \expandafter\cf@add
  \else
    \expandafter\cf@checknum
  \fi
}

% Checks if token is a number (ASCII 48-57)
\def\cf@checknum#1{%
  \ifcase 0%
    \ifnum`#1>47
    \ifnum`#1<58 1\fi\fi
  \relax
    \def\next{\cf@end#1}%
  \else
    \def\next{\cf@add{#1}}%
  \fi
  \next
}

\def\cf@add#1{%
  \edef\name{\name#1}%
  \cf@
}

\def\cf@end{%
  \let\type\name
  \edef\name{\name:}%
  \def\cf@end{%
    \edef\@tempa{%
        \endgroup
        \type\noexpand~%
        \noexpand\ref{\name}%
    }%
    \@tempa
  }%
  % Remove colon
  % support active colons (e.g. `[french]{babel}`)
  \scantokens{\expandafter\let\csname cf@colon\endcsname=:}%
  \@ifnextchar\cf@colon%
    {\expandafter\cf@\@gobble}%
    {\cf@}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{test}\label{sec:test}
\section{test}\label{sec:tes1}
\section{other}

\cf sec test it out
\cf sec:test it out

\cf sec
tes1 it out  % numbers and line break work

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Martin: Wow! Don't you think this ought to be packaged and distributed? It would make the life of so many people sweeter. It would also be cool also to add a flag that would either produce the long version, i.e., Section~1, or the short version Sect.~1... More later.

Comment: @Yossi: I personally think people should stick with explicit `\ref{sec:name}`. Feel free to turn it into a package. Just mention me somewhere in the manual.

Comment: @Martin: I like the use of `\ifcase 0`, which expands the following tokens to see whether `0` will be followed by a digit or not. And that next digit continues the expansion until reaching `\relax`, so the conditionals are fully expanded (no spurious `\fi`) before `\ifcase` is evaluated. Neat.

Comment: @Bruno: I didn't came up with this technique by myself but learned it somewhere (on [comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/topics) I think)

Comment: @Martin: your colon handling mechanism will fail with `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}` which makes `:` active (the second reference will always remain `??`).

Comment: Thanks @Philippe, I forgot that. I added a fix for it. Now the colon is taken with the currently used catcode. There are other ways to do this which avoid the use of the eTeX primitive `\scantokens`, but this solution is quick and simple.

Comment: @Martin: You didn't _come_ up `:-)`

Comment: @Martin: small issue. The macro you defined does not take two arguments as in `\def\cf #1 #2 {#1~\ref{#1:#2}}`

Comment: @Yossi: Sure it does. See the example code at the end which works fine for me. The `\cf@end` macro is executed *twice*, the first time it adds only a colon to the name and redefines itself to be the real end-macro for the second time a non-suitable character is found.

Comment: I am not sure this is quite what I meant. But, this is unimportant. The important thing is that you cracked it. I will post my rewrite of your code so that you will see what I mean.

Comment: @Yossi: Sorry, I totally overlooked the first `#1` before `\ref`. Yes, my macro doesn't do that, but it can be added.

Comment: @Martin: wouldn't it be simpler to change the catcode of ":" to be letter or other?

Comment: @Yossi: This wouldn't be reliable. The `:` might already be read beforehand and the catcode would then already be fixed. Also if the second word ends with a colon, which is not taken as part of the word, it would be placed back to the input stream and might be required to be active. This things are difficult to get 100% right for all possible use cases.

Comment: @Yossi: also I updated my code a while back to handle the first `#1` correctly. I forget to inform you right away.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rewrite of Martin's code. First the use case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cf}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\paragraph{Outline.}
In \cf Section things we shall discuss things, and then continue to discuss
stuff in \cf Section stuff; \cf Section final concludes.
\section{Things are so Important}\label{Section:things}
\section{Stuff is also Important}\label{Section:stuff}
\section{Conclusions}\label{Section:final}
\end{document
```

which produces
[image]

now, the rudimentary style file is

```
\def\cf #1 {%
  \def\kind@cf{#1}%
  \beginIteration@cf
}

\def\beginIteration@cf{%
  \begingroup
  \def\idAccumulator@cf{}%
  \iterateOnNextToken@cf
}

\def\iterateOnNextToken@cf{%
  \futurelet\nextToken@cf
  \examineNextToken@cf    
}

\def\examineNextToken@cf{%
  \ifcase 0% Trick: will expand the next tokens to see if more digits follow. 
    \ifx\nextToken@cf\@sptoken 0\else
    \ifcat a\nextToken@cf 1\else
    \ifcat 0\nextToken@cf 2\fi% test of token is catcode "other"
    \fi\fi
  \relax
    \expandafter\endIteration@cf
  \or
    \expandafter\accumulateCharacter@cf
  \else
    \expandafter\cf@checknum
  \fi
}

\def\accumulateCharacter@cf#1{%
  \edef\idAccumulator@cf{\idAccumulator@cf#1}%
  \iterateOnNextToken@cf
}

% Checks whether the parameter is a number (ASCII 48-57)
\def\cf@checknum#1{%
  \ifcase 0%
    \ifnum`#1>47
    \ifnum`#1<58 1\fi\fi
  \relax
    \def\next{\endIteration@cf#1}%
  \else
    \def\next{\accumulateCharacter@cf{#1}}%
  \fi
  \next
}

\def\endIteration@cf{%
  \edef\label@cf{\kind@cf:\idAccumulator@cf}%
  \kind@cf~\expandafter\ref\expandafter{\label@cf}%
  \endgroup
}
```